# Text above whole window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a C# Application with WPF.
I want a text above my whole main window. It should look like this:

http://s2.postimg.org/uqad6sosp/Capture.png

The window should keeping interactive and the user should work with the application. So the text is only a watermark on the window.

Have anyone a idea how can i do this with xaml?

Comment: Have you tried google? This question implies you have done zero research.

Comment: @DanielKelley google would be too much for him, since it seems like placing a grid around his content and then placing the textbox at the very top of the XAML code outside the grid is too demanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place a Label on top inside the applicationWindow. Then set IsHitTestVisible=False. This should do the trick. Of course you can start using Adorners, but that's maybe too much right now...

```
 <Grid>
        <Your Stuff here />
        <TextBlock Text="My Watermark" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="45pt" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DoSomeRotation... />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

Add a resource like this,

```
<Window.Resources>
               <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF7D8683" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollhost" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="lblwatermark" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="lblwatermark" Value="Visible"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

**XAML:**

```
     <Grid >
    <TextBox  Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Height="50" FontSize="43"  Tag="OFFLINE">
        <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-43" />
        </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```